# Cannot open pickle file because of missing module which created it

Tags: python, pickle

I've created a pickle file using a python file which uses a custom module I made, named module_v9.py . Now I've done some insignificant modifications and saved the module as module_v10.py, and when I try to open the pickle .p file I get the error saying "no module named module_v9.py". How does it know the name of the module that created it, and why can't I just open this pickle file containing one single dictionary object? When I rename the module to v9, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

From [pythons documenatiton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) you can see:

> "Note that functions  are pickled by fully qualified name, not by
> value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with
> the name of the containing module and classes. Neither the function’s
> code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the
> defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and
> the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will
> be raised. "

> "Similarly, classes are pickled by fully qualified name, so the same
> restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that none of
> the class’s code or data is pickled."

> "Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and
> data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are
> pickled. This is done on purpose, so you can fix bugs in a class or
> add methods to the class and still load objects that were created with
> an earlier version of the class. If you plan to have long-lived
> objects that will see many versions of a class, it may be worthwhile
> to put a version number in the objects so that suitable conversions
> can be made by the class’s **setstate**() method."

Comment: I still don' get it. My pickled dictionary contains class instances. The class definition is found in both module_v9.py and module_v10.py. So why is the name of the file important?

Comment: Because "Similarly, classes are pickled by fully qualified name, so the same restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that none of the class’s code or data is pickled." The name is pickled not the code or data